# JsonMappingException using Jackson - mistakenly places a field in the wrong class

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, deserialization

so I am getting a JsonMappingException with what I consider to be a weird error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "CoTravellers" (Class JobPush), not marked as
>   ignorable at [Source: java.io.StringReader@416a60a0; line: 1, column:
>   947] (through reference chain: >JobPush["CoTravellers"])

Now, what I have is this:

```
ProtocolContainer --> JobPush (inherits from DataPacket) --> Job --> CoTravellers
```

The JobPush, mentioned in the error above, is a sub-class of DataPacket. So, the ProtocolContainer has one DataPacket, and I have several classes inheriting DataPacket, where JobPush is one.

The JobPush is simple, looks like this:

```
public class JobPush extends DataPacket 
{
    public Job Job;
}
```

*and it is in the Job-class that the CoTravellers field exists, not in the JobPush*:

```
public class Job implements Serializable
{
    @JsonDeserialize(using=CustomMapCoTravellerDeserializer.class)
    public Map<Objects.CoTravellers, Integer> CoTravellers;

    // ....
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use a custom deserializer ([see here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543119/how-do-i-correctly-deserialize-net-dictionaries-using-jackson)).

**Now, I cannot understand why I get an error saying that there is no field "CoTravellers" in JobPush? I never said that CoTravellers is in the JobPush, as it is inside the Job-class.**

The JSON I am parsing looks like this (this is cropped a bit for clarity, where SubPacket is the variable name, holding the DataPacket which in this case is a JobPush):

```
"SubPacket":{
    "__type":"JobPush:#DataPackets.ToVehicle",
    "Job":{
    "CoTravellers":[
        {
           "Key":{
              "CoTravellerId":0,
              "Name":"Medresenär"
           },
           "Value":1
        }
     ]
     }
}
```

Anyone out there who can clue me in? =)

**---- EDIT 1 ----**

Adding some stuff, for clairity:

So, classes inherit from the class "DataPacket", and thus I have used @JsonSubTypes annotation to deal with that. This is the DataPacket-class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="__type")
@JsonSubTypes(
{
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = JobPush.class, name = "JobPush:#DataPackets.ToVehicle"),
})
public class DataPacket 
{
}
```

Comment: Did you configure Polymorphic type handling (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for Jackson or rely on the default settings?

Comment: I have Polymorphic settings. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

you talk about a CoTraveller field, but in the JSON it is CoTravellers with an 's' on the end.

Comment: There is a class called CoTravellers, with the s at the end. The field in the class Job is also called CoTravellers, so the field in the class Job is like this:
*public Map<CoTravellers, Integer> CoTravellers;*

Comment: Do you have a getCoTravellers() method in your JobPush class?  If so it needs to be marked as @JsonIgnorable for Jackson to not assume there should be data in there.

Comment: Nops, there is nothing more in the JobPush class than what you can see above.